# MediaRecorder stop called in an invalid state: 1

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a call recorder app ,and I'm facing this problem when i receive incoming calls my app runs fine ,there are no exceptions.But when i call someone I'm getting some errors.Please don't write dumb answers like "can you explain more" and than to down vote.I think that the problem might be when i start recording ,and that it can't stop.But I'm not sure about it.
Here is my code:

The PhonecallReceiver.java

```
public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing
    ......

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
       ......

        //Toast.makeText(context,"Reciever", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        } else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    public void onIncomingCallAsnwered(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    public void onIncomingCallIdle(Context ctx,String number,Date start){}


    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if (lastState == state) {
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {


            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);


                PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener(context, number);
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                } else if (isIncoming) {
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                } else {
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }


    //Detect if call is answered
    private class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public boolean wasRinging;
        Context context;
        String number;

        public PhoneStateChangeListener(Context context, String number) {
            this.context = context;
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.i("Call recorder::", "RINGING");
                    wasRinging = true;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500); // Delay 0,5 seconds to handle better turning on
                        // loudspeaker
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                   // context.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);



                    Log.i("Call recorder::", "OFFHOOK");

                    onIncomingCallAsnwered(context, number, callStartTime);

                    if (!wasRinging) {
                        // Start your new activity
                    } else {
                        // Cancel your old activity
                    }

                    // this should be the last piece of code before the break
                    wasRinging = true;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.i("Call recorder::", "IDLE");
                    // this should be the last piece of code before the break
                    onIncomingCallIdle(context, number, callStartTime);
                    wasRinging = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the CallReceiver.java which is an extension to the PhoneCallReciever.java

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    private String fileName;
    private boolean recording = false;


    //Phone Ringing From Incoming Call
    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onIncomingCallStarted Phone:" + number);
    }

    //Phone Outgoing Call Started
    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onOutgoingCallStarted Phone:" + number);
        if (is_recording) {


            startRecording(number, ctx, "outgoing", false);


        }

    }

    //Phone Incoming Call Ended
    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onIncomingCallEnded Phone:" + number);
    }

    //Phone Outgoing Call Ended
    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onOutgoingCallEnded Phone:" + number);
        if (is_recording) {
            stopAndReleaseRecorder(ctx);
        }


    }

    //Phone Call Missed
    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onMissedCall Phone:" + number);
    }

    //Phone Incoming Answered<--Main
    @Override
    public void onIncomingCallAsnwered(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onIncomingCallAsnwered Phone:" + number);
        if (is_recording) {


            if (is_record_contacts_only && new FileHelper().is_number_in_contacts(ctx, number)) {
                startRecording(number, ctx, "incoming", false);
            } else if (!is_record_contacts_only) {
                startRecording(number, ctx, "incoming", false);
            }


            if (is_record_all_except_contacts && !new FileHelper().is_number_in_contacts(ctx, number)) {
                startRecording(number, ctx, "incoming", false);
            } else if (!is_record_all_except_contacts) {
                startRecording(number, ctx, "incoming", false);
            }

        }

    }

    //Phone Incoming Call Idle
    @Override
    public void onIncomingCallIdle(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "onIncomingCallIdle Phone:" + number);
        if (is_recording) {
            stopAndReleaseRecorder(ctx);
        }

    }


    /*

    Call feature

     */


    //Recording
    private void terminateAndEraseFile(Context context) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService terminateAndEraseFile");
        stopAndReleaseRecorder(context);
        recording = false;
        deleteFile();
    }

    private void deleteFile() {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService deleteFile");
        FileHelper.deleteFile(fileName);
        fileName = null;
    }

    public void stopAndReleaseRecorder(Context context) {
        Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "Stoped recording");
        if (recorder == null) {
            Log.d("Call recorder:: ", "nill");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService stopAndReleaseRecorder");
        boolean recorderStopped = false;
        boolean exception = false;

        try {
            recorder.stop();
            recorderStopped = true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IllegalStateException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "RuntimeException");
            exception = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }
        try {
            recorder.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }
        try {
            recorder.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }

        recorder = null;
        if (exception) {
            deleteFile();
        }
        if (recorderStopped) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.receiver_end_call), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    public void startRecording(String phoneNumber, final Context context, String incoming_or_outgoing, boolean is_missed) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService startRecording");
        boolean exception = false;
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();


        try {


            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            fileName = FileHelper.getFilename(phoneNumber, incoming_or_outgoing, is_missed);
            recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
            Log.d("Name of file", "" + fileName);


            MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                public void onError(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "OnErrorListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                    terminateAndEraseFile(context);
                }
            };
            recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

            MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "OnInfoListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                    terminateAndEraseFile(context);
                }
            };
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

            recorder.prepare();
            // Sometimes prepare takes some time to complete
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            recorder.start();
            recording = true;
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService recorderStarted");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IllegalStateException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = true;
        }

        if (exception) {
            terminateAndEraseFile(context);
        }

        if (recording) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.receiver_start_call), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.record_impossible), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the error that I'm getting :

```
 RecordService stopAndReleaseRecorder
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder E/MediaRecorder: stop called in an invalid state: 1
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder E/Call recorder:: IllegalStateException
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at free.call.automatic.recorder.helper.CallReceiver.stopAndReleaseRecorder(CallReceiver.java:133)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at free.call.automatic.recorder.helper.CallReceiver.onOutgoingCallEnded(CallReceiver.java:53)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at free.call.automatic.recorder.helper.PhonecallReceiver.onCallStateChanged(PhonecallReceiver.java:151)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at free.call.automatic.recorder.helper.PhonecallReceiver.onReceive(PhonecallReceiver.java:84)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-29 13:16:02.586 19691-19691/free.call.automatic.recorder D/Call recorder:: RecordService deleteFile
```

Comment: you are starting to record while the recorder is recording. In your `OnOutgoingCallStarted()` method, you do it like: `if (is_recording) startRecording` ....I guess it must be `if(is_recording==false)`....with this, you are initializing the media recorder again while it is already initialized...

Comment: no that's just an option from the sharedprefs that im disabling the call recording option in the app

Comment: ah ok, then there is only one possible cause: it´s not started while you call stop. This is pointed out in the API: `Throws IllegalStateException  if it is called before start() ` . So it´s important to know, when exactly the error is thrown. By starting outgoing call or if it rings or if it´s hooked up by the called person?

Comment: I think that it might be the same problem I'm going to try to find it out

Comment: The thing is that I'm getting from the log that the recording has been started

Comment: ok, I see you get this error in `onOutgingCallEnded()`. So just an assumption: You are stopping in that method like this: `if (is_recording)`. And if `is_recording` is a value inside sharedPreferences, then the recorder is not necessarily started. In that case, you have to write `if(recording)` because `recording` is the value that you set to true if the recorder starts successfully...

Comment: So it´s possible that something went wrong while you want top start and the recorder isn´t started....then the error is thrown because you are try to stop a not started recorder...

Comment: I guess your startRecord method throws some exception and you haven´t seen it. Read your log carefully and remove your tags in the logcat output. It´s possible that some of the important messages aren´t shown there, because you set different Tags.

Comment: I have removed the is_recording and I'm still getting the same problem this drives me crazy really

Comment: yes for sure...ok, let´s do it step by step. Removing  `is_recording` is not enough. You have to replace it by `recording`, not only delete it. The next is, if I am right, you get an error while creating the mediaplayer. So possibly, the file path is wrong.

Comment: Look i know that the code is working when someone calls me so incoming calls,but when i make them and when i call the same code it's crashing

Comment: Let´s try something. Deinstall your app, reinstall it. Then the very first thing you have to do is, start a call. Don´t use it by an incoming call. Then we can be sure, that it isn´t because your MediaRecorder isn´t reseted correctly if the incoming call finished. You have to be sure that you can read your logs correctly, Sometimes, an error can be only a result of another, earlier error. So it´s very important to delete all filters from logcat and search the complete logcat for a possible cause.

Comment: I have done it,still the same problem.I had a problem at the beggining it might be that.My onCallStateChanged made a problem ,it was detecting the calls but when i wanted to recording incoming calls it crashed there.Than i created a new PhoneStateChangeListener and i have solved there the incoming call problem ,now when i want to record it from the first one it's crashing.Take a look at the code

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in your PhonecallReceiver class. Why you are making your own "PhonecallReceiver" ? I guess, the usual TelephonyManager will do the job. Sorry, but the code of your PhonecallReceiver is very confusing.Somewhere you are not following the API for a proper MediaRecorder object, but, sorry, I can´t figure out where. This is really too much to check....

Comment: I wanted to get the incoming,outgoing,incoming end,outgoing end options for my app and missed call also

Comment: yep, and I guess that somewhere your methods are called multiple times. But when or where, can only be detected with an exact logcat output, that´s not possible for me because I haven´t that app..

Answer (score 5):

Above code snippet is correct only but before doing this you must need to ensure with below points :

- MediaRecorder is already stopped and your trying again to stop it :
  Exception
- If MediaRecorder is already released and you are trying again to
  release it : Exception

The correct order of configuration mentioned in camera developer guide on android documentation

- Set audio/video source, format,encoder
- Prepare
- Start

Comment: there is no need for camera unlock, Mickey only records audio and camera is not needed. And there is no hint inside the API that it must be done if audio is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in the order of these statements because I have faced the same issue few months back I don't remember the right order but you can confirm it from developer.android documentation

```
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            fileName = FileHelper.getFilename(phoneNumber, incoming_or_outgoing, is_missed);
            recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where can we find the list of state code? I think this is the key to solve related problems.

As for this issue, what does the state 1 mean? We all know the state diagram, but we just do not know the code for each state.

And eventually, I found that the meaning for

- 1: Initial, if I call stop() twice, the 2nd time will tell this.
- 2: ?
- 3: ?
- 4: ?